# SQL-Server CONCAT case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following exercise:

> concatenate first, middle, last name and name suffix to form the
>   customer’s name in the following format: FirstName [MiddleName.]
>   LastName[, Suffix]. Note that NULL values should be omitted.

I interpret this as the following scenario (created the table from the image and inserted some values):

Please find my sample data below, name is #TB_Customer
[image]
The column **CustomerName is the expected result** and should be of form

- `FirstName MiddleName.LastName, Suffix` if i have enteries for all
  the fields.
- MiddleName and Suffix can be optional, so the cases are:
- If there is a `suffix` but not a `MiddleName` then `CustomerName`
  should be of form `Firstname LastName,Suffix`
- If there is a `MiddleName` but not a `suffix` then `CustomerName`
  should be of form `FirstName MiddleName.LastName`
- If both `MiddleName` and `Suffix` are null then `CustomerName` should
  be of form `FirstName LastName)`

This is what i'm getting:
[image]

But as you can see the CustomerName case query I wrote doesn't work as expected (please see the `cases` above with bullets)

The query I wrote to get the `CustomerName` column is:

```
SELECT 
(case
when (MiddleName is not null and Suffix is not null)  then
CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME,' ', c.MiddleName,'.', c.LASTNAME, ', ',Suffix)  
when (MiddleName is null and suffix is null) then 
CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME,' ' ,c.LASTNAME) 
when (MiddleName is null and Suffix is not null )then
concat (c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName, ', ',Suffix )  
when (Suffix is null and MiddleName is not null) then
concat (c.FirstName, ' ',MiddleName,'.',LastName)
end 
)AS CustomerName
,c.*
FROM   #TB_Customer c;
```

I have 2 questions:

- Did I understand the exercise and do i have a good logic?
- Where have I made a mistake and what's the correct query?

Using SQL-Server 2012

**edit**

to recreate my scenario please see the code below (sorry for not linking a fiddle but the website is not responding at my current location)

```
CREATE TABLE #TB_Customer
(
CustomerID int , --PK
Title varchar(50),
FirstName varchar(50),
MiddleName varchar(50),
LastName varchar(50),
Suffix varchar(50),
EmailAddress varchar(50),
Phone varchar(50),
Gender varchar(50),
Birthdate varchar(50),
--no fk
PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
)

insert into #TB_Customer values
('1','Sir','John','Jacob','Adams','St','johnJacobAdams@gmail.com','0677731235','M','1989-04-06'),
('2','Mr.','Russel','Thyrone','Peterson','pr','thyronePeterson@yahoo.com','555-010405','M','1963-02-01'),
('3','Ms.','Anne','Candice','Acola','aca','CandiceA@gmail.com','07408989989','F','1988-05-19'),
('4','Mrs.','Sophia','Veronika','Turner','tvs','SophiaVT@facebook.de','0423423887','F','1983-06-20'),
('5','Ms','Margaret','','Delafleur','','delaMarg@yahoo.co','233223355','Female','1982-02-25'),
('6','Mrs','Jessica','Luana','Cruz','','Jess@yahoo.com','787876631','Female','1922-05-05'),
('7','Mr','Dyrius','','Cruz','dc','dyr33@yahoo.com','0673332211','Male','1987-03-01')

update #TB_Customer
set Gender = 'Male' where Gender = 'M'
update #TB_Customer
set Gender = 'Female' where Gender = 'F'
```

Comment: @DanBracuk please see line 5 from the expected result. That is not ok. Also line 7

Comment: How are we supposed to see that your query doesn't work, when you don't show the result? Furthermore you list three cases and your code has four, and in a rather strange order.

Comment: So your "Expected result" is not actually what you expect, but what you actually get?

Comment: @Henrik there are 4 cases, the first one is the scenario in which every field is `not null`. The expected value of the column is in the bullet list. Will edit and put the 4th case with a bullet

Comment: @Henrik you are right, it wasn't perfectly clear, sorry. I edited it. Hope it's ok now

Comment: Do you realize that you are checking for NULL but there is not a single NULL anywhere in your sample data?

Comment: should probably assume that '' = NULL

Comment: @SeanLange oh, I thought that blank means NULL , I see. Then how can i do it? Because the problem is formulated with null values and I just created that table. Should I first do an update table and set columns to null where there is a blank?

Comment: Actually your code seems to be ok but your test is not valid because you don't have NULLs in your test data.

Comment: @SeanLange , Yea, I thought that `bank` = `null` guess, I was wrong. You have my vote, learned something today

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this should work as well...

```
SELECT concat(firstname
     ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(middlename,'') <> '' THEN ' '+middlename+'.'
        WHEN ISNULL(middlename,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(suffix,'') = '' THEN '.' 
        ELSE ' ' END
     ,lastname
     ,CASE WHEN ISNULL(suffix,'') <> '' THEN ', '+suffix END)
FROM #TB_Customer
```

OUTPUT:

```
John Jacob.Adams, St
Russel Thyrone.Peterson, pr
Anne Candice.Acola, aca
Sophia Veronika.Turner, tvs
Margaret Delafleur
Jessica Luana.Cruz
Dyrius Cruz, dc
John Adams, St
```

Comment: marked as answer for offering a working solution which doesn't use `coalesce` (was trying to do it only with cases, thanks)

Comment: @Doolius `WHEN ISNULL(middlename,'') <> '' AND ISNULL(suffix,'') = '' THEN '.'`, will this condition be evaluated ever? I ask this because if `middlename` is `NOT NULL` then the first `WHEN` condition will be executed always.

Answer (score 5):

I cant see the error in you query, i know if one of the columns is null, all the others will be, but try this way:

```
SELECT COALESCE(c.FIRSTNAME,'') + ' ' +
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(c.MiddleName,'') = ''
                THEN ''
                ELSE c.MiddleName + '.'
            END
        + COALESCE(c.LASTNAME,'') +
        CASE WHEN COALESCE(Suffix,'') = ''
                THEN ''
                ELSE  ', ' + Suffix
             END AS CustomerName, c.*

FROM   #TB_Customer c;
```

@Henrik is right, '' and NULL are diferent things

Comment: this gives for line 5 (please see the 2nd picture). `Margaret .Delafleur, ` Should give `Margaret Delafleur` , without the dot or the comma

Comment: Edited, but the picture show a dot before Delafleur

Comment: this works great, thanks. Accepted Doolius' answer because it doesn't use coalesce, was looking only for cases (but great solution, has my upvote)

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've given the code, I can see what the error is: The empty string is different from NULL.

So your tests for the presence of a middle name/suffix will always be true.

Either set those fields to NULL, or augment the test to check for NULL or empty strings.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know how to "check for NULL or empty strings" . Ideas?

Comment: You check for NULL with "field IS NULL" and for empty strings with "field = ''", and combine those with AND or OR (and possibly some parentheses) just like you already have.

Comment: tried it like this, doesn't work:`SELECT 
(case
when (MiddleName is not null and Suffix is not null)  then
CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME,' ', c.MiddleName,'.', c.LASTNAME, ', ',Suffix)  
when (MiddleName is null or MiddleName = '') and (suffix is null or suffix = '') then 
CONCAT(c.FIRSTNAME,' ' ,c.LASTNAME) 
when (MiddleName is null or MiddleName = '' ) and (Suffix is not null )then
concat (c.FirstName, ' ', c.LastName, ', ',Suffix )  
when (Suffix is null or Suffix = '')and MiddleName is not null then
concat (c.FirstName, ' ',MiddleName,'.',LastName)
end 
)AS CustomerName
,c.*
FROM   #TB_Customer c;`

Comment: sorry for making it messy, but fiddle doesn't work for me here. Did I get your point?

Comment: It's really hard to read, but I don't think that will work. As far as I can see, the case where both the MiddleName and Suffix is '' you will hit the first case - but where you have added a check for the empty string it looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    STUFF(RTRIM(
        CONCAT('  ',
            COALESCE(NULLIF(FirstName,'') + ' ', ''),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(MiddleName,'') + '.', ''),
            COALESCE(NULLIF(LastName,''), ''),
            COALESCE(', ' + NULLIF(Suffix,'') , '')
        )
    ), 2, 0,'')
FROM #TB_Customer tc
```

added the `STUFF` incase for some strange reason all you have is a Suffix

Comment: this works great, thanks. Accepted Doolius' answer because it doesn't use coalesce, was looking only for cases (but great solution, has my upvote)

Comment: @CM2K Thanks.. you might want to look at this also.. it forms the name the way you'd actually want to see it if you were creating some sort of name label.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76d65/1  Only using periods for middle initials and such